# Configuring Executor and Driver memory in Spark-on-Yarn

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, mapr

I am confused with configuring executor and driver memory in Spark-1.5.2.

My environment settings are as below:

```
3 Node MAPR Cluster - Each Node: Memory 256G, 16 CPU 
Hadoop 2.7.0 
Spark 1.5.2 - Spark-on-Yarn
```

Input data information:

460 GB Parquet format table from Hive
I'm using spark-sql for querying the hive context with spark-on-yarn,but it's lot slower than the Hive, and am not sure with the right memory configurations for Spark,

These are my config's,

```
    export SPARK_DAEMON_MEMORY=1g
    export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=88g

    spark.executor.memory              2g
    spark.logConf                      true
    spark.eventLog.dir                 maprfs:///apps/spark
    spark.eventLog.enabled             true
    spark.serializer                   org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
    spark.driver.memory                5g
    spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max    1024m
```

How to avoid Spark java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space exceptions and
GC overhead limit exceeded exceptions!! ???

Really appreciate your assistance in this!

Comment: have you tried spark.executor.instances which will be the number of you spark workers in the cluster ?

Comment: Thanks dumitru. I've added that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a first glance, you are running out the memory of your executors. I would suggest increasing their memory.

Note that SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY is only used in standalone mode. SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY is used in YARN mode.

If you are not running anything else on the cluster you could try out the following config:

```
spark.executor.memory   16g
spark.executor.cores    1
spark.executor.instances 40
spark.driver.memory  5g (make it bigger if expected 
                         final result dataset is larger)
```

I do not recommend to set a large executor memory because that typically increments the GC time. Other thing I see, it is that those instances are memory optimized. Think twice if this fits your case.

Comment: Hi Luis...Thanks for the details. I've tried with large executor memory and more than 40 executor instances and the result is GC Overhead exceeded in spark-sql but i can run the same query in Zeppelin with Spark Interpreter, it takes roughly 41 minutes to complete, Hive completes within 15 mins with the same 480GB input. Is there any other parameter configurations for the better performance ??

Comment: Have you been able to run the query successfully?

Comment: I can run the query successfully in Zeppelin but not with spark-sql cli.In spark-sql cli am getting the GC overhead exceptions.

Comment: Hi Luis...the environment variables in spark web-ui shows master.spark =local[*] !!! this supposed to be "yarn-cluster" right? if it's wrong, how to change the spark.master!!